# Meet with error when running GetStarted example of IoT DevKit

Tags: iot-devkit

After running automated install script, I opened GetStarted example - and am getting AZ3166wifi.h, AzureIoTHub.h, DevKitMQTTClient.h and SystemTickCounter.h not found errors in VSCode "problem" tab.

"file: 'file:///c%3A/Users/alias/Documents/Arduino/generated_examples/GetStarted_1/GetStarted.ino' severity: 'Info'
message: '#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. IntelliSense features for this translation unit (c:\Users\alias\Documents\Arduino\generated_examples\GetStarted_1\GetStarted.ino) will be provided by the Tag Parser.'
at: '4,1'

source: ''"

I re-ran the automated script and had no errors. Add the additional url as directed by the manual install page. Still the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those files exists in our Arduino AZ3166 package. 
You could find them under C:\Users{your username}\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\AZ3166\hardware\stm32f4\1.2.0\cores\Arduino and C:\Users{your user name}\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\AZ3166\hardware\stm32f4\1.2.0\libraries.

It is not included in mini solution folder as when compiling the code, the compiler would auto find those files.
We are working on the fix for the Intellisense problem.